# Overflow icon color in < API 21

Tags: android, android-layout, menuitem, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

In my app I have toolbar constructed in this way:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/LzTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/LzTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and styled in this way:

```
<style name="LzTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/LZ_green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/LZ_green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/LZ_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/LZ_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/LZ_dark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/LZ_green_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="LzTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="LzTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

In versions android >=21 overflow icon color is white - the desired color.
[Image API 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWJHy.png)

In Api <21 overflow icon color is dark. 
[Image API <21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU4WB.png)

Can anybody explain why how to make icon white in API below 21??

Thank for help.

Comment: Are you using AppCompat v23.2.0? Did you follow the instructions in the [Support Library 23.2 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) to enable support vector drawables? That's required.

Comment: Yes 23.2.0. I test in V23.1.0 and problem was that same. However, use of support vector drawable in 23.2 fixes a problem. Thank for help.

Comment: Check Theme in **values-21** -> **style.xml** !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AppCompat v23.2.0, you must follow the instructions in the [Support Library 23.2 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) to enable support vector drawables as that is required to get this to work:

For Gradle 2.0+, this involves adding the line `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your `defaultConfig` in the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

Override next style in base theme of Your app:

```
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow</item>

<style name="Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/action_menu_overflow_description</item>
</style>
```